# Obtener Departamento de usuario en Active Directory con Membership en MVC5 C#

Tags: c#, ldap, directorioactivo, activedirectory, mvc5

Requiero su ayuda para obtener el departamento de los usuarios del Active Directory usando el Membership class.

Ya he logrado conectarme y usar metodo para verificar usuario, pero no he conseguido un metodo para sacar el departamento que trabaja el usuario.

```
        var test = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        if (test.IsApproved)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

                return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        }
```

Podrian ayudarme con esto?

Gracias

He intentado tambien con la clase System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement sin embargo me da error de usuario y contraseña y no se donde se debe verificar

```
            var test4 = Membership.GetUser("Name");


        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com", "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com"))
        {
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, test4.Email))
            {
                var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
            }
        }
```

[image: This is the error I get]

Answer (score 0):

Buscar el departamento con la clase Membership creo que es imposible, Intentalo con Galactic API, creo si tiene metodos para ello

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]